# How do I install PDCurses in Windows for use with C++?

Tags: c++, pdcurses

I want to use it in some of my programs instead of the standard IOStream.

Also, does NCurses work on Windows, and if so, any better?

Comment: I'm not sure which IDE you use, but for Visual Studio this is a good guide: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708392/install-pdcurses-on-visual-studio-2017

Answer (score 6):

[Download the zip file](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdcurses/files/pdcurses/), unpack it wherever you typically put external libraries, and check the readme, which tells you the following:

> PDCurses has been ported to DOS, OS/2, Win32, X11 and SDL. A directory containing the port-specific source files exists for each of these platforms. Build instructions are in the README file for each platform.

The readme file in the Win32 directory tells you that there are makefiles for several different compilers. In short, you run `make`:

```
make -f makefilename
```

It tells mentions a couple of options you can set, including WIDE and UTF8.

To then *use* the library, add the directory that contains *curses.h* to your include path and link with the *pdcurses.lib* file that `make` generates for you. How you modify your include path and your linked libraries depends on your development environment and is largely irrelevant to PDCurses.

Comment: For me, the readme says:  PDCurses Portable Core
======================

This directory contains core PDCurses source code files common to all 
platforms.


Building
--------

These modules are built by the platform-specific makefiles, in the 
platform directories.


Distribution Status
-------------------

The files in this directory are released to the Public Domain.


Acknowledgements
----------------

The panel library was originally provided by
Warren Tucker <wht@n4hgf.mt-park.ga.us>

Comment: OK, @Evorlor. That seems to say pretty much the same thing, no? Was there something you meant to add to this?

Comment: guess not. i thought i was making the point that it doesnt tell u how to install PDCurses.  But i guess i was making the point that i just dont understand it

Comment: After 3 hours, I gave up on PDCurses.  Now I am just trying to Console::SetCursorPosition(int, int);, but I can't even seem to get that working :-/

Comment: @Evorlor Idk if this will help you, but the instructions here [PDCurses MinGW tutorial](http://comptb.cects.com/adding-pdcurses-to-mingw/) helped me to install PDCurses for my C application using MinGW.

Answer (score 4):

## On VSCode

### [Step 1] Install MinGW :

- [MinGW](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_example-install-mingwx64) installation steps
- *^(make sure you followed the steps carefully)*

### [Step 2] BUILD PDCurses:

- Download [PDCurses-master.zip](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/archive/refs/heads/master.zip) and extract the content
- Open\Run `MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit` *(or `MSYS2 MinGW 32-bit`<sup>^1</sup>)*
- `cd` into the `wincon` folder and run `make -f Makefile WIDE=Y DLL=Y` <sup>[source](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/blob/master/wincon/README.md)</sup>

### [Step 3] Copy Files:

If you followed the steps above so far correctly, there should be 2 specific files inside `wincon` folder called `pdcurses.a` and `pdcurses.dll`

- rename `pdcurses.a` to `libpdcurses.a`
- copy `pdcurses.dll` into `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`
- copy `libpdcurses.a` into `C:\msys64\mingw64\lib`
- copy `curses.h` and `panel.h` form `PDCurses-master` folder into `C:\msys64\mingw64\include`

### [Step 4] Build an example:

- Install [the C/C++ extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)
- Follow those [steps](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp#_hello-world) to create a working enviroment inside VSCode
- Add `"-lpdcurses"` under `"args":` into `tasks.json`
- and you are Done *(at least those steps worked for me)*

## Extra

- you can also just manually build an example by runing `g++ your_example.c -o your_example -lpdcurses` inside `MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit` terminal if you want so [...]
- <sup>**^1**</sup> if you want to build for 32 systems a good rule is to follow all steps above but wherever you see 64 replace it with 32
- [demos / examples](https://github.com/wmcbrine/PDCurses/tree/master/demos)

#### how things should look like:

[image]

- **c_cpp_properties.json**

```json
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win64",
            "includePath": [
                "${default}"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.17763.0",
            "compilerPath": "C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

- **launch.json**

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

- **tasks.json:**

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-lpdcurses"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally made it. First Build/Compile the Source according to docs.

```sh
make -f Makefile # did for me, Windows 10
```

Copy `curses.h` and `panel.h` into your `include` folder. And, Copy `wincon/pdcurses.a` into your `lib` folder. Rename `pdcurses.a` to `libpdcurses.a`. (Because it's the standard).

Now, You can include `curses.h` and compile it like this.

```sh
g++ main.cpp -lpdcurses
```