# NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'Makefile.vc' not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pdcurses

I'm trying to do the steps as mentioned in [Install pdcurses on Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708392/install-pdcurses-on-visual-studio-2017), which tells me to boot up the Developer Command Prompt for my VS(2019), and write
`set PDCURSES_SRCDIR=D:\PDCurses-3.9\PDCurses-3.9(my path for PDCurses)`  but I was stuck at step 2:

> Navigate in the command window to the directory of PDCurses/wincon*
> `nmake –f Makefile.vc*`
> (This is the make file for PDCurses.) It will create the pdcurses.lib for our Visual Studio.

What I then typed into my command prompt:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>`nmake -f Makefile.vc`

What I received:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.20.27508.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

NMAKE : fatal error U1052: file 'Makefile.vc' not found
Stop.
```

I'm really confused as to why this is happening. I've been trying to search and only found these:

- https://github.com/blackrosezy/build-libcurl-windows/issues/19
- [How to download, build and include PDCurses in Visual Studio 2019 for C++ on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63553274/how-to-download-build-and-include-pdcurses-in-visual-studio-2019-for-c-on-win?noredirect=1&lq=1) (wants me to input the commands in the Native Tools Command Prompt, not the Developer Command Prompt. Any difference?)

both links mention a .bat file. Where do I find this file?

Thanks to anyone who can help!

*: modified from original source for updating purposes

Comment: You must run the `nmake` command in "*the directory of PDCurses/wincon*", not in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community`.

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked that, it was right in front of my face. I think you should make this into an answer to mark this question as resolved, and anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>nmake -f Makefile.vc`

This is running `nmake` in the wrong directory, causing the `file 'Makefile.vc' not found` error.

The `nmake` command must be run in "*the directory of `PDCurses/wincon`*" as mentioned in a previous step. Assuming `PDCURSES_SRCDIR` has been set already, this can be done with a `cd` before `nmake`.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>cd /d %PDCURSES_SRCDIR%\wincon

D:\PDCurses-3.9\PDCurses-3.9\wincon>nmake -f Makefile.vc
```