# Element<Runtime Library> has an invalid value of "Multithreaded Debug(/MTd)"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pdcurses

I'm also having this (seemingly) related error:

`MSB6011: Invalid parameters passed to the Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL task.`
The reason why they may be related is that both errors were going to the same line (line 423) in the same file (Microsoft.CppCommon.targets):

```
<CL Condition="'%(ClCompile.PrecompiledHeader)' != 'Create' and '%(ClCompile.ExcludedFromBuild)'!='true' 
and '%(ClCompile.CompilerIteration)' == '' and @(ClCompile) != ''"
```

---

I was trying to change the Runtime Library value in

Configuration Properties>C/C++>Code Generation>Runtime Library (path)

from "Default" into "Multithreaded Debug(/MTd)" to set up PDCurses on Visual Studio 2019, with help from [Install pdcurses on Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708392/install-pdcurses-on-visual-studio-2017) (I was on step 3), which led to these two errors:

```
1.Element<Runtime Library> has an invalid value of "Multithreaded Debug(/MTd)"

2.MSB6011: Invalid parameters passed to the Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.CL task.
```

Not sure what went wrong, but I have a feeling that these might help:

- I changed the "Include Directories" in "VC++ Directories" from '$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);'
  into '$(VC_IncludePath);$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath);***D:\PDCurses-3.9\PDCurses-3.9***'
- Changed the "Library Directories" in "VC++ Directories" from
  '$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86);$(NETFXKitsDir)Lib\um\x86;'  into '$(VC_LibraryPath_x86);$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86);$(NETFXKitsDir)Lib\um\x86;***D:\PDCurses-3.9\PDCurses-3.9\wincon***'
- Put "pdcurses.lib" in "Additional Dependencies" in the "Input" tab of the "Linker".

Any help given is appreciated!

Comment: You aren't using c++-clr or c++-cli by any chance?

Comment: Did you type in the value rather than selecting it from the drop down list?

Comment: @AlanBirtles 
1.Where can I check it?

2.I didn't see any drop-down list when typing in the changes

Comment: The arrow button on the right of the box? If you've typed in the value thats almost certainly the cause of the problem, just select one of the values from the list

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, it worked! Thank you very much! I suggest you make an answer to mark this question as resolved