# How install pdcurses in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, pdcurses

I followed this instruction [Install pdcurses on Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708392/install-pdcurses-on-visual-studio-2017)

But i get error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ed3Pt.png)

Comment: Please at least post errors in English?

Comment: Have you tried the `vcpkg install pdcurses` advice?

Comment: Oh,sorry.I have uploaded a screen of errors in English

Comment: Cleary you're missing some `lib`s added to linker dependencies in newly created project ([say step 3 does that](https://jdonaldmccarthy.wordpress.com/2014/09/05/how-to-set-up-pdcurses-in-visual-studio-2013-c/))